# Parsing PySerial Data from queue and executing function on command match

Tags: python, pyserial

I've created a thread that 'puts' incoming serial data from a host into a queue object.  The host sends variable length ascii characters that are terminated with a carriage return/line feed.

In the main loop thread I'm grabbing the data this way:

```
try:
     while True:
        qCount = list( self.dataQ.get_nowait( ) )
except queue.Empty:
    raise StopIteration
```

However I don't want to manually get each character in the queue to form a string and then compare against a list of valid commands..    How do I treat the queue contents as a string and do the compare?

I'm learning python from a 'c' background.. in the world of 'c' I would have created an array of struct type that has a string element and a function pointer element.   As it strncmp each element, if it matches it would execute the associated function pointer.    What would be the pythonic way of doing something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queue would transfer any object and since every transaction is costly, it'd be better to transfer strings through it. I.e. collect characters from serial and put to queue string when CRLF is met.

Then, on receiving end, you can detect command directly from item that you'll get, since it'll be complete string. There are many ways to do what you have described with "C" analogy depending on design of command interface. But in simplest case, it could be just dictionary:

```
cmds = {}
cmds['name1'] = func1

try:
     while True:
        str = self.dataQ.get_nowait()
        cmd_name, cmd_params = str.split(' ', 1)
        try:
            res = cmds[cmd_name](cmd_params)
        except:
            ## command not found
            pass 
except queue.Empty:
    raise StopIteration
```

Comment: I've got the thread that reads the serial data to detect the carriage return byte (b"\x0D") and the main thread now works off complete command strings.    But even though I've created a 'def func1 (self):' function above the function that declares 'cmds['name1] = func1',   it says that 'func1' is not defined.   Is there something else that's needed to make this work?

Comment: @ben then you should add to cmds dictionary not func1 but self.func1, and move initialization of cmds to some init code for example __init__(self,..).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that worked!   Between when to use 'self' and all the indentation rules, the transition from c hasn't been a walk in the park!